# Gmail SMTP REQUIRES an "app password"?

Tags: email, passwords, smtp, gmail

I need to make a program sending emails using the Gmail smtp server. Everything works fine except for one thing. In order to make it work, I had to go on my google account and create an app password otherwise it wouldn't send and told me I had to do that. So my question is, does Gmail absolutely require you to have an app password in order to send emails from an application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to authenticate with the Gmail SMTP server in order to send mail.

This means either using your Google account password (or better - a Google account password for a new account with no sensitive information in it), or an app password if you have 2FA enabled on your Google account.

Answer (score 3):

[Since May 2022, Google stopped providing access to less secure apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)

### Steps to generate an app password to integrate programmatically

1. Go to the Google account.
2. On the left navigation panel, click Security.
3. On the "Signing in to Google" panel, click App passwords. If prompted, enter your password.

Note: If you can't get to the page, 2-Step Verification is:
Not set up for your account

4. Make sure Mail or Other (custom name) is selected in the Select app drop-down menu. If you seelcted Mail, choose a computer or device from the Select device menu. If you selected Other (custom name), type the application name (like "My Mail Program").
5. Click Generate.
   Use the generated password displayed BOTH IN IMAP and SMTP section in your email account settings in Program SMTP Setting.

Answer (score 1):

The Google account password does not work anymore.  For Gmail personal users, you have to use the "App password".   For paid Google Workspace users, there are more options, such as "Less secure apps" or "Google SMTP relay service".  See https://www.cubebackup.com/blog/how-to-use-google-smtp-service-to-send-emails-for-free/ for more information.